# has_many through a has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following classes:

company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
end
```

person.rb

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_and_belongs_to_many :trades
end
```

trade.rb

```
class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :people
end
```

And my join table:

```
create_table "people_trades", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer "trade_id"
  t.integer "person_id"
end
```

I would like to place an association on Company that returns a distinct list of all Trades related to the Company's People. Any ideas?

I tried making the following change as suggested:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
  has_many :trades, through: :people, :uniq => true
end
```

But that generates the following SQL which fails on the ORDER BY clause. Trades do not have first/last name fields, people does though.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "trades".* FROM "tratrades"."id" = "people_trades"."trade_id" 
INNER JOIN "people" ON "people_trades"."person_id" = "people"."id" 
WHERE "people"."company_id" = ? 
ORDER BY "trades"."name" ASC, "trades"."last_name" ASC, "trades"."first_name" ASC  [["company_id", 1]]
```

Comment: in your query you can change .distinct http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I've found a bug. If I have default scopes on Person and Trade, I get the screwed up ORDER BY clause. If I remove the scopes, things work.

Comment: sometimes ORM fails so you can try putting the query yourself.  using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SQL query")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
  has_many :trades, through: :people
end
```

`company.trades` should then give you all the trades that belong to people in the company.

Comment: Tried that bit it didn't work. Updated original question with more details.

Comment: I had default scopes with order clauses in my Company, Person, and Trade models. Once I removed them this worked.